# How to pass an object through url in .net core using httpget method?

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In .net core i use one controller method. that method is httpget method. That method has to receive the object as a parameter. In client side i Just pass the parameter like as

```
let data ={
"Id":1,
"Name":"xxx"
}
http://localhost/controller/GetObject?model=data
```

In controller side method is

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetObject([FromBody]ViewModel model)
{
}
```

The controller method definitelly will be a httpget. I don't know how to do it using .net core? If anyone knows please convey..

Answer (score 2):

`HTTP GET` doesn't have a "body". You're passing this data in as a query parameter.

You either need to pass each param in via the query:

```
http://localhost/controller/GetObject?id=1&name=xxx
```

and then include parameters from your controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetObject(int id, string name)
{
}
```

or you need to use an `HTTP POST` post and pass in the data as part of the body.

Comment: its not a simple object.I passed more than 15 parameters. That is a issue. i can't pass 15 properties as a parameter. So how can i pass this object. I tried with FromQuery. It also doesn't support. it always receive null value. If have anyother solution just let me know

Comment: What you're describing is what HTML forms and  `POST` were designed for. Get "gets" data, Post "sends" data. You can fudge a little with `GET` but it isn't suitable for submitting that many parameters.